# ROS groovy catkin laser_assembler cmake error

Tags: ros, catkin, laser-assembler, ros-groovy, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi i get the following cmake error when I try to build a project with the laser_assembler

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package laser_assembler.

  Set laser_assembler_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration
  file for laser_assembler.  The file will have one of the following names:

    laser_assemblerConfig.cmake
    laser_assembler-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  spherical2_cartesian/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:244 (message):
  Messages depends on unknown pkg: laser_assembler (Missing
  find_package(laser_assembler?))
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  spherical2_cartesian/CMakeLists.txt:71 (generate_messages)
```

I am not sure why. I added the package to the build and run dependency in the package.xml Added the laser_assembler package to the required components and added the package name in the
"Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here"
generate_messages() command.

The documentation says the package is compatible with groovy...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/108721/ros-groovy-catkin-laser_assembler-cmake-error/) by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 418 on 2013-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This means that your package cannot find `laser_assembler` in your `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`.

If you installed `laser_assembler` from `apt-get`, you need to make sure you ran `source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash` before trying to build your package.

If you are building everything from source then you need to make sure that `laser_assembler` is in your workspace or in a previous workspace which you have sourced.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on 2013-12-10**:
Hi i am using the catkin_package. Also when I roscd I can find the laser_assembler package but I noticed it has a manifestfile, so I suppose it may have be built using rosbuild. My quick fix was to manually copy the .srv file I needed and copy it to my packages srv folder.

**Comment by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on 2013-12-10**:
are their any issues with catkin packages finding stuff in rosbuild packages?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-12-10**:
Yes, in groovy `laser_assembler` is a rosbuild package, it was converted to catkin in hydro. catkin packages cannot depend on rosbuild packages, only rosbuild packages can depend on other rosbuild packages. So in groovy your package would have to be rosbuild if you wanted to depend on `laser_assembler`.